# .js.erb file available to all other views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-handling

So, in my rails app I ajaxified the error messages on one of my pages. the process was (so everyone understands) first, in my 'edit' `link_to` I added `:remote => true` at the end of it thus having it send an ajax request. I then added the line `format.js` in my `respond_to do |format|` block. Then, I made an edit.js.erb file with the following line of code `$('#error').html("<%= flash[:error] %>");`  which basically finds the error div in the current page and replaces the html in that div with the error flash message. This is cool right? No more annoying page refreshes in the event of an error.

Question is, I want to do this for all my edit and destroy pages, but how without making an edit.js.erb and destroy.js.erb file for each view folder? seems pretty simple, and maybe im just missing an obvious answer because I'm exhausted, but I can't figure it out... so... help?????

EDIT!

this is my edit controller

```
def edit
user = User.find(session[:id])
@table = Table.find(params[:id])



if user.id != @table.created_by

  flash[:error] = "ERROR"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :template => 'shared/show_error'}
    format.html
  end
else
  flash[:error] = ""
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :template => 'table/edit', :formats => :html}
    format.html
  end

end
end
```

Problem now is, it works fine for showing the errors but if there are no errors it doesnt action render the edit page... In the server window it shows it did, but it doesnt actually show on the screen... Any ideas?

Comment: Don't put `:formats => :html` within your `format.js` call.

Comment: thanks, but that was not the fix :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed my own problem by accident... I removed the line `{render :template => 'table/edit', :formats => :html}` from the `else` block.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you then make a general JS.erb file, something like:

```
# app/views/shared/show_errors.js.erb
('#error').html("<%= flash[:error] %>");
```

And then in your controller action, or from another JS.erb file, just type:

```
render :template => "shared/show_errors"
```

And voila!